# Google Maps API search based on geolocation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the same question posted here: [How do I search using the Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465716/how-do-i-search-using-the-google-maps-api).  They mentioned the answer helped, but I still couldn't figure it out.  Does anyone have an example of it working or can post the code?

I can get it to work seperately, find your geolocation and also search for restaurants (by typing in coordinates); but I can't seem to combine it into one map that finds your geolocation and then searches for nearest items based on your geolocation.  Any ideas on how to make that happen on one map?  Or I'd settle for 2 pages, if someone knows how to pass the variables of your geolocation to another page/map to search for restaurants.